# Datatables and DateTime format of interval between dates not sortable

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

I have an Invoices table of Due dates and Paid dates.  I have a 3rd column that is the time between paid and due date.  I use DateTime and format to get how many days late the payment was.

```
            $pDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$paidDate);
            $dDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$dueDate);
            $pDate = new DateTime($pDate);
            $dDate = new DateTime($dDate);
            $diff = $pDate->diff($dDate);
            $pastDueFormat = $diff->format('%a');
```

I have tried change format to

```
$pastDueFormat = $diff->format('%d');
```

I have all this data in a table formatted by DataTables

```
$('#invoices').dataTable();
```

The problem is, I cant get sort to recognized 39 days as a number, or even 39 for that matter.  my sort results are always

94
91
9
88
85
8....

when clearly i want
94,91,88,85,9,8.....

Comment: You've to deal with the datatable, because its responsible for the column sorting, its sorting that column as if its string but not number, I got this problem, the solution I've done is that I changed - in the datatable config js code - the column which sorting would be based on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like DataTables isn't so smart after all. You can explicitly provide the column type like this:

```
$('#invoices').dataTable({'columnDefs': [{'type': 'num', 'targets': 0}]});
```

The value of the `'targets'` key should equal the index of your column, 0-based.